# How to get a substring from string through PHP?

Tags: php

Hi want to change the displayed username like abcd@somedomain.com to only abcd.
so for this i should clip the part starting from @.

I can do this very easily through variablename.substring() function in Java or C# , but I m not aware with the syntax of PHP.
So help me do that .

Suppose i m having variable like .

```
$username = "abcd@somedomain.com";
$username = some
```

string manipultion functiona should get called here ;
so that
echo $username; 
can results in abcd only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$username = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, '@'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) function.

An example from the PHP reference -

```
<?php
    $email  = 'name@example.com';
    $domain = strstr($email, '@');
    echo $domain; // prints @example.com

    $user = strstr($email, '@', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
    echo $user; // prints name
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list($username, $domain) = explode('@', 'asdf@somedomain.com')
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php).

```
$username = strtok($email, '@');
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/zTuOxq3l).

Answer (score 2):

```
substr(string, 0, 20)
```

String, start, length

Comment: hey i can't hardcode 20 everytime how to get index of @ there

Comment: you can find the position of @somedomain.com using strpos().

Comment: no, this is just an example, for a more robust way to you can use regular expression with preg_replace() see the documention on php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$crop_username = substr($username, 0, strpos($username, '@'));
```

This will help you