# Get a substring of a string

Tags: php, string, substring, substr, strpos

I've been trying to get a substring of a string that contains around 40 lines of text.

The string is something like this but with aprox. 30 more lines:

```
Username: example
Password: pswd
Code: 890382
Key: 9082
type: 1
Website: https://example.com/example
Email: example@example.com
```

I need to get the value of, for example, `Code` which will be `890382`, but I can't seem to do it.

Each field like `Code` or `Key` is unique in the string. The best (if possible) would be to read the values and store them in an array with positions named after the fields. If someone could help me with this I would be grateful.

BTW: This file is hosted in a different server which I only have access to read so i can't change it into something more CSV like or something.

Code i've tried to use:

```
$begin=strpos($output, 'Code: ');
$end=strpos($output, '<br>', $begin);

$sub=substr($output, $begin, $end);
echo $sub;
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Of course! I've tried strpos using the the string as haystack and the name of the field as needle in order to get the beginning of the substring, then i tried to use the same thing but using the previous result of strpos as the beginning, and <br> and the needle to get the ending position. Afterwards i tried to use substr to get the substring using the beginning and ending positions. It didn't work... (Btw, i use nl2br to convert \n to <br>)

Comment: ^ Then show us your work and your attempts! Show your code.

Comment: do you have google in your country? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752594/how-to-get-a-substring-from-string-through-php

Comment: @user3676792 Just [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29917945/edit) your question and add your code

Comment: @Rizier123 It is not necessary, Dan Bizdadea provided a useful solution and also Thomas Schober. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3676792 *It is not necessary* Of cores it is! 1. It improves the quality of your question 2. We see where you are stuck, so we can help you better and explain exactly the things which you don't understand and where you are stuck; We also see that you don't just ask for code, but that you also tried something

Comment: @PedroLobito The funny thing is, eu, também, sou português. E sim, temos Google cá, caso não saibas. Agradeço desde já a tua resposta que foi deveras útil (o link talvez, o sarcasmo nem por isso...).

Comment: @Rizier123 Sure, i'll do some CTRL-Z and get the code. I'm sorry if i was wrong in not putting the code in the question. Thanks

Comment: @user3676792 for something so simple you should have searched SO or  Google before posting your question.

Comment: @user3676792 Just use the edit button under your question and also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to format your code nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split each line, and then split on the colon sign. And put the key/pairs into an array:

```
$string = "..."; // your string
$lines = explode("\n",str_replace("\r","\n",$string)); // all forms of new lines
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $pieces = explode(":", $line, 2); // allows the extra colon URLs
    if (count($pieces) == 2) { // skip empty and malformed lines
        $values[trim($pieces[0])] = trim($pieces[1]); // puts keys and values in array
    }
}
```

Now you can get your value by accessing `$values['Code']`

Comment: perfect! did everything i wanted after some tweaks. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Here I first [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your string by a new line character. After this I go through each element with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), where I explode it again by `:`. Then I simply `array_combine()` the first array columns with the second columns, which I get with `array_column()`.

```
<?php

    $str = "Username: example
            Password: pswd
            Code: 890382
            Key: 9082
            type: 1
            Website: https://example.com/example
            Email: example@example.com";

    $arr = array_map(function($v){
        return array_map("trim", explode(":", $v, 2));
    }, explode(PHP_EOL, $str));

    $arr = array_combine(array_column($arr, 0), array_column($arr, 1));

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [Username] => example
    [Password] => pswd
    [Code] => 890382
    [Key] => 9082
    [type] => 1
    [Website] => https://example.com/example
    [Email] => example@example.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the ending position of Username: and then find starting position of Password. Then Use these values to extract the username value. Like this find what value you want...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is separated by a line break, you can try this:

```
$str = "Username: example

        Password: pswd

        Code: 890382

        Key: 9082

       type: 1

       Website: https://example.com/example

       Email: example@example.com";

$explode = explode("<br/>", $str);
foreach ($explode as $string) {
     $nextExplode = explode(":", $str);
         foreach($nextExplode as $nextString) {
             if ($nextString[0] == 'Code']) {
                 echo $nextString[1];
             }
          }
     }
```

Comment: If explode not possible with <br/>, user can convert all line breaks with a whitespace using str_replace function. and then can proceed by explode function using needle as whitespace. Isn't it?

Comment: This code will never work. First of all, there is no `<br/>` in the string. It's not html. Second you are exploding, and foreaching a string, and then taking a piece and treating it like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a split delimiter "\n" and/or ':' which will then provide you an array where you can further dissect into key value pairs.

In the following example, I took the approach to read from file, and split by ":\s" given a line.

**ie. example with 'data.txt'**

```
<?php

$results = array();

$file_handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
   $line = fgets($file_handle);
   $line_array = preg_split("/:\s/", $line);

   // validations ommited 
   $key = $line_array[0];
   $value = $line_array[1];

   // ie. $result['Code'] => '890382' 
   $result[$key] = $value;
}
fclose($file_handle);

print_r($result);

?>
```

**Output Usage ie.echo $result['Username']:**

```
Array
(
    [Username] => example

    [Password] => pswd

    [Code] => 890382

    [Key] => 9082

    [type] => 1

    [Website] => https://example.com/example

    [Email] => example@example.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
preg_match('/Code: ([0-9]+)/', $subject, $matches);
```

You should have the code in the $matches array.

You should adjust the regexp so it will fit your case. I just put an example.

Answer (score 0):

In your special case use following code:

```
preg_match('/Code\:\s*(.*)\s*/m', $yourstring, $match); 
$match[1] //contains your code!
```