# PHP search inside loaded text file, converted as array

Tags: php

I need to find a `*.jpg` name in a text document. For example I have a folder with pictures `file1`, `file2` , `file3` and a text document with `file1`, `file`, `file3` each on a new line. I need to write near each `*.jpg` the text from the file, but first I need to find the corresponding row in the text document.

```
 <?php
 $arrayF = explode("\n", file_get_contents('myTxt.txt'));
 // arrayF should the the array with each text line from the txt file.
  while(($file = readdir($opendir)) !== FALSE)
       {
           if($file!="." && $file!="..")
           {
                $string=$file;
                $arrayS = explode('.', $string);//get the name only without .jpg extension
                $search=$arrayS[0];

        $key = array_search($search, $arrayF);

        echo $key;
       }
```

Comment: So you have a file with image file names (1 name = 1 line?!) and you want to display them without extension ? 1. Please add an example how the text file looks like and what your expected output would be

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: I got multiple jpg for example picture2.jpg, and the text file looks like this 
picture1 
dimension_30x30
picture2 
dimension_40x50
picture3 
dimension_10x10  (Pictures name and dimension are in separate lines each).

So i need to find for picture2.jpg what dimension should i add near the picture.And i try to search the line then the line+1 is the correct answer.

Comment: I mean i try to find the picture2.jpg name in the txt file...and i i fond the line i can get the line+1 which is the dimension..but array_search function dont work for me..

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to iterate through a directory using [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) which provides viewing contents of filesystem directories.

Example:

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $file_info)
{
    // sleep a micro bit (up to 1/8th second)
    usleep(rand(0, 125000));

    // disregard hidden, empty, invalid name files
    if($file_info == null or $file_info->getPathname() == '' 
                          or $file_info->isDot())
    {
        continue;
    }

    // check if its a file - log otherwise
    // code omitted

    // get filename and filepath
    $filepath = $file_info->getPathname();
    $filename = $file_info->getFilename();

   // my answer to read file linked here to avoid duplication
   // below "read/parse file into key value pairs"
}
```

## [read/parse file into key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917945/get-a-substring-of-a-string/29918119#29918119)

To elaborate `new DirectoryIterator( path to dir )` provides an iterator which can be also written as:

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
  // do stuffs
}
```

Hope this helps, indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string=file_get_contents($file);
```

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Or if you want it line by line, just [open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) and [close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');
while ($line = fread($fp)) {
//do comparision stuff
}
fclose ($fp);
```