# Extract exact letters from a string

Tags: php, string, substring

Lets say I have this string:

```
CNVFJD-0905-05-BX
```

CNV will always be there  , same with the first '`-`'.

What I need is to 'extract' whats between CNV and the first line(in this example I would need 'FJD'.

I don't really know how to approach this.

Thank you.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Maybe `CNV([^-]+)`, with `preg_match` then pull index 1.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a substring from string through PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752594/how-to-get-a-substring-from-string-through-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substr, try this

```
substr($sring, 3, strpos($string, '-'));
```

Answer (score -1):

With `sscanf`:

```
$str = "CNVFJD-0905-05-BX";
sscanf($str, "CNV%[A-Z]-", $result);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score -4):

```
$parts = explode("-", $string);
$result = substr($parts[0], 3);
```

See here for working example https://3v4l.org/pRJ3e

Comment: @aryamccarthy why is my answer in more need of explanation than the two other answers here? Don't tell me you think the two words Casimir wrote is an explanation?

Comment: I didn't DV but I can imagine it was done because while the code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.